# mysql query to search from json not returning data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search a record from a table which is having a json data in one field

field names in database table are username and data

```
1, {"body":"Hello ", "id":"1"}

SELECT * FROM table where username = 1 and data like '%"body":"Hello"%'
```

but it returns nothing. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `h != H`. if you're on a case-senstive collation, then `hello` will never match `Hello`.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry I have edited the question, it still returns nothing

Comment: "Hello " != "Hello" - the space inside string